# Проблема в bash

Tags: python, django, bash

Работаю в bash'e, балуюсь с отладочным веб-сервером в Django и возникает такая картина при попытке запуска веб-сервера python manage.py runserver. Синтаксис во всех файлах urls/views.py правильный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В последней строке написано же белым по черному.

Comment: спасибо большое, но я не могу понять, где исправить строковые литералы

Comment: очевидно в файле, который упомянут ещё на две строчки выше. и даже номер строки приведён.

Comment: Учётная запись случаем не на русском?